# Redirect to URL throught Android's captive portal browser

Tags: android, redirect, captiveportal

I have configured my Meraki AP so that when a device is connected to it automatically opens a splash page with a "Continue to the internet" button. The goal is that when the button is pressed the connection is authorized and also redirects to another URL (even to the apple store / google play).

My button:

```
<a href="<?php print $ base_grant_url."?continue_url=http://myURL"?>">
    Click here to continue to the internet 
</a>
```

In iOS it works fine. In Android only works until Android 5.1 (API 22). In later versions when launching the splash page through the captive portal, when you press the button, it starts loading the specified page but instantly closes the captive portal.

The user is authorized and can browse but I can not redirect him to the page that I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the normal behavior in the last Android API.